# How to organize categories and subcategories of products in menus?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

I have product content type that I want to display in a menu. Every product belongs to subcategory that belongs to main category, for example:

```
Computers:
   PC:
      - product 1
      - product 2
      - product 3
   Laptop:
      - product 1
      - product 2
      - product 3
   Tablets:
      - product 1
      - product 2
      - product 3

Phones:
   Android:
      - product 1
      - product 2
      - product 3
   iOS:
      - product 1
      - product 2
      - product 3
```

When clicking on products item in main menu, I need to display a horizontal menu with main categories (Computers, Phones) and a vertical menu with subcategories (PC, Laptop, Tablets). Computers > PC should be the default selection. Whenever any category/subcategory is selected it should display a list of links to the product page.

What are the most common modules use to do something like this? Are there any tutorials or basic steps I can take to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 0):

while you want to display category, sub category and node at the same time, so you have to use views. 
you can use group by in the views and groups the results depending on category and subcategory.

but you also mention that you don't want to show product unless you click on the subcategory, to get this there is many ways, the simplest one is create view that shows the category and subcategory, when you click on it it will drive you automatically to the taxonomy page.

if you don't want to use views you can use taxonomy modules in Drupal there are a lot of them.